# java regex, reading folders

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to creating a program that returns the name of all video files and folders in a file. I already found the pattern for the video files and it works fine

```
String pattern = "(^\\w[ .A-z0-9_-]+(\\.mp4$|\\.avi$|\\.mkv$))";
```

But im stuck on how to read the folders, everything I've tried has the pattern reading folders, but also other files as well. Since the folder name may have dots anywhere, its hard to isolate by extensions. Any ideas on how to read only folders?

Comment: I don't know if it's intentional but your A-z has an uppercase 'A' and a lowercase 'z'

Comment: You have to call the `File.isDirectory()` method.

Comment: or keep a list of known extensions and use a negative match on that (Gross, unmaintainable, and unreadable.)

Comment: Thanks, File.isDirectory() is what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code (with help from BalusC) for finding the filenames and their extensions.

If you have got the regex right then just plug it in here and add rest of the code as per your requirements.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    File[] files = new File("temp").listFiles();
    showFiles(files);
}

public static void showFiles(File[] files) {
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
            showFiles(file.listFiles()); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());
            getFileNameAndSuffix(file);
        }
    }
}
public static void getFileNameAndSuffix(File file) 
{
    int index = file.getName().lastIndexOf('.');
    System.out.println(file.getName().substring(0, index));
    System.out.println(file.getName().substring(index));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, File.isDirectory() is what I needed